# Failed to access the MailCore Classes in any other classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mailcore

I have added the MailCore.xcodeproj in my application, and set the Header Search Path, Library Search Path and Framework Search Path like as it is set in Remail application. But when I am accessing the classes of the MailCore (like CTCoreAccount, CTCoreFolder, etc)  after import in any other class and creating an object like this:

```
#import "CTCoreAccount.h"
CTCoreAccount* account = [[CTCoreAccount alloc] init];
```

I will get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTCoreAccount", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ImapSync.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I think your import statement is wrong.

You should be using a relative header - and just use the top level one for the framework:

```
#import <MailCore/MailCore.h>
```